# Is it correct use for Django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

My question; i'm used ModelForm instead of forms.Form and i want to organize form in html file instead of forms.py file  (i don't want to use **attr** tag because my form.html file is very complicated) Is this usage correct?

forms.py

```
 class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Comment
        fields=[
            'name',
            'email',
            'comment',
        ]
```

html file

```
<form class="post-comment-form" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% if form.errors %}
          {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
              {{ error }}
          {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}

<div class="form-row">              
  <div class="form-item half blue">
    <label for="id_name"  class="rl-label" >Name</label>
    {{ form.name}}
  </div>

  <div class="form-item half blue">
    <label for="id_email" class="rl-label" >Email</label>
    {{ form.email}}
  </div>              
</div>

<div class="form-row">             
  <div class="form-item blue">
    <label for="id_comment"  class="rl-label">Comment</label>
    {{ form.comment }}
  </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="save-button">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use the `{{form}}` then you have to give the input field for each model's fields like `<input type="text" name = "name">` .For example

```
 <div class="form-row">              
      <div class="form-item half blue">
        <label for="id_name"  class="rl-label" >Name</label>
        **<input type="text" name = "name">**
      </div>

      <div class="form-item half blue">
        <label for="id_email" class="rl-label" >Email</label>
        <input type="text" name = "email">
      </div>              
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">             
      <div class="form-item blue">
        <label for="id_comment"  class="rl-label">Comment</label>
        <input type="text" name = "comment">
      </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="save-button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Can i use " {{ form.name }} " instead of " <input type="text" name = "name"> "

Answer (score 0):

On the html you can have something like this

```
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
```

and then proceed with styling or better yet you can use `{% crispy %}` which personal I find it great based on what you want to archive, your forms.py looks ok.

Comment: I don't want to use {{form}} because have nested class